# Gradle: Force Custom Task to always run (no cache)

Tags: groovy, build, gradle

I wrote up a custom Gradle task to handle some dependency resolution on the file system where the paths are configurable. I want tasks of this type to always run. It seems though they only run once, I'm guessing because the inputs never seem to change.

I am aware of using `configurations { resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds' }` to effectively disable the cache, but I only want it to apply to very specific tasks. Also am aware of `--rerun-tasks` command line prompt, which is also similar. Neither feel like the best solution, there must be a way to set this up properly in the custom task definition.

Follows is my current implementation. I also had a version prior where the first 3 def String statements were instead @Input annotated String declarations.

```
class ResolveProjectArchiveDependency extends DefaultTask {
    def String archiveFilename = ""
    def String relativeArchivePath = ""
    def String dependencyScope = ""

    @OutputFile
    File outputFile

    @TaskAction
    void resolveArtifact() {
        def arcFile = project.file("dependencies/"+dependencyScope+"/"+archiveFilename)
        def newArcFile = ""

        if(project.hasProperty('environmentSeparated') && project.hasProperty('separatedDependencyRoot')){
            println "Properties set denoting the prerelease environment is separated"
            newArcFile = project.file(project.ext.separatedDependencyRoot+relativeArchivePath+archiveFilename)
        }   else {
            newArcFile = project.file('../../'+relativeArchivePath+archiveFilename)
        }

        if(!newArcFile.isFile()){
            println "Warn: Could not find the latest copy of " + archiveFilename + ".."

            if(!arcFile.isFile()) {
                println "Error: No version of " + archiveFilename + " can be found"
                throw new StopExecutionException(archiveFilename +" missing")
            }
        }

        if(!arcFile.isFile()) {
            println archiveFilename + " jar not in dependencies, pulling from archives"
        } else {
            println archiveFilename + " jar in dependencies. Checking for staleness"

            def oldHash = generateMD5(new File(arcFile.path))
            def newHash = generateMD5(new File(newArcFile.path))

            if(newHash.equals(oldHash)) {
                println "Hashes for the jars match. Not pulling in a copy"
                return
            }
        }

        //Copy the archive
        project.copy {
            println "Copying " + archiveFilename
            from newArcFile
            into "dependencies/"+dependencyScope
        }
    }

    def generateMD5(final file) {
       MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
       file.withInputStream(){is->
       byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]
       int read = 0
          while( (read = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                 digest.update(buffer, 0, read);
             }
         }
       byte[] md5sum = digest.digest()
       BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, md5sum)
       return bigInt.toString(16)
    }
}
```

Here's an example of usage of the task:

```
task handleManagementArchive (type: com.moremagic.ResolveProjectArchiveDependency) {
    archiveFilename = 'management.jar'
    relativeArchivePath = 'management/dist/'
    dependencyScope = 'compile/archive'
    outputFile = file('dependencies/'+dependencyScope+'/'+archiveFilename)
}
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting `outputs.upToDateWhen { false }` on the task.

This can be performed in your `build.gradle` file:

```
handleManagementArchive.outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
```

It can also be done in the constructor of your custom task.

```
ResolveProjectArchiveDependency() {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the link to this interesting blog entry. As pointed out there, this is _not_ the proper mechanism for rerunning tests. The question here though was about getting a custom task to always run. If the task uses other results from the build cache, those tasks will not be executed, but as far as I understand, this task will.

Comment: Good point, if you're sure the task itself isn't cached then it should be okay. I'm never sure what tasks the cache will cover so I like to use something that works everywhere!

Comment: @Steinar Does this disable the Gradle Build Cache too? 
Or do I also need to add `outputs.cacheIf{ false }` (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskOutputs.html#cacheIf-org.gradle.api.specs.Spec-) to the task?